# Use groupby or aggregate to merge items in each transaction in RDD or DataFrame to do FP-growth

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I want to change the dataframe with this structure to the second one.

```
+---+-----+-----+
| id|order|items|
+---+-----+-----+
|  0|    a|    1|
|  1|    a|    2|
|  2|    a|    5|
|  3|    b|    1|
|  4|    b|    2|
|  5|    b|    3|
|  6|    b|    5|
|  7|    c|    1|
|  8|    c|    2|
+---+-----+-----+
```

change it to this:

```
+---+-----+------------+
| id|order|       items|
+---+-----+------------+
|  0|    a|   [1, 2, 5]|
|  1|    b|[1, 2, 3, 5]|
|  2|    c|      [1, 2]|
+---+-----+------------+
```

How can I do it in PySpark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Groupby` order with `collect_list` function and a unique id with `row_number` should work in your case

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df.groupBy("order").agg(F.collect_list("items"))
   .withColumn("id", F.row_number().over(Window.orderBy("order")))
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

you can do

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
df.groupBy(df.order).agg(collect_list("items").alias("items"))
```

**Edited**

in case you want to do the same in rdd, you can do the following (scala)

```
rdd.groupBy(x => x._2).mapValues(x => x.map(y => y._3)).zipWithIndex()
```

Given the rdd as

```
(0,a,1)
(1,a,2)
(2,a,5)
(3,b,1)
(4,b,2)
(5,b,3)
(6,b,5)
(7,c,1)
(8,c,2)
```

the result would be

```
((a,List(1, 2, 5)),0)
((b,List(1, 2, 3, 5)),1)
((c,List(1, 2)),2)
```